# Reposition Scroll Bar - Excel Office Add-In

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am using hide/showing/freezing columns in my Add-In and sometimes I end up with none of the 'data' columns showing. I wondered if I could reset the scroll bar to the left somehow w/ the new Excel Office-JS API?

I googled around and found nothing, so it may not be possible or I didn't have the right 'google fu', but I haven't tried anything as of yet as I couldn't find anything to try. If the answer is that its impossible, that is definitely an answer! (Though not the one I want obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such API published and implemented for web add-ins. You can file a feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .